# Stylus/SpriteSmith - Serve 2x (Retina) images using same sprite file?

Tags: gulp, css-sprites, stylus

I'm using Stylus + Rupture + SpriteSmith + Gulp.JS and I wanna know if its possible to serve 2x version of an image using same sprite.png file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

### We actually can serve a 2x version of our image from the same sprite file.

The main idea is that inside the media query, we have to divide all the numbers by 2 and add the ***background-size*** property.

If you are using **plain CSS** or **Stylus**, you might use something like:

```
#logo {
    background-image: url("sprite.png");
    background-position: -230px -93px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 45px;
}
@media not all, only screen and (min-resolution: 1.5dppx), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (min-resolution: 144dpi) {
#logo {
    background-position: -70px 0;
    background-size: 150px 93.5px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 45px;
}
}
```

Note : The real position, size and dimensions of our sprite is different, But we are actually scaling down the sprite image and changing positions accordingly.

If you are using Stylus + SpriteSmith, you could write a Sprite_2x function like this :

```
spriteWidth_2x($sprite) {
  width: ($sprite[4]/2);
}

spriteHeight_2x($sprite) {
  height: ($sprite[5]/2);
}

spritePosition_2x($sprite) {
  background-position: ($sprite[2]/2) ($sprite[3]/2);
}

spriteImage_2x($sprite) {
  background-image: url($sprite[8]);
}

sprite_2x($sprite) {
  spriteImage_2x($sprite)
  spritePosition_2x($sprite)
  spriteWidth_2x($sprite)
  spriteHeight_2x($sprite)
  background-size ($spritesheet_width / 2) ($spritesheet_height / 2)
}
```

By the way, I don't understand why many articles out there suggest to use a separate sprite file for 2x images. I believe this way we could reduce 1 extra request which is way more efficient. I don't know maybe I am wrong. I'm new to this.